# How to HTML post with authorization token and JSON arguments in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, http, post

I'm creating a VB.NET program that I'd like to interface with dropbox.  I'm starting with the "list_folder" command which will return the contents on a specified path.  Here is the URL where you can play with the command:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_list_folder

The HTTP request syntax provided is as follows:

```
 POST /2/files/list_folder
 Host: https://api.dropboxapi.com
 User-Agent: api-explorer-client
 Authorization: Bearer HBNBvdIls8AA12AAFTvyzhNJrdwwpQcswxpRVjmwRIJANPIea7Jc1Ke
 Content-Type: application/json
 {
     "path": "/Backups"
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is the equivalent in a VB.NET command.  Here's what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim uri As String = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder"
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.UserAgent = "api-explorer-client"

    ' this is wrong, need to supply an 'authorization token' somehow:
    Dim credentials As New Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    request.Credentials = credentials

    request.ContentType = "application/json"

    'request.ContentLength  = ???
    ' how do I set content to the "path: backups" data?

    Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

    Debug.Print(response.StatusDescription)

    Dim dataStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(dataStream)          ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()  ' Read the content.

    MsgBox(responseFromServer)  ' Display the content.

    ' Cleanup the streams and the response.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

End Sub
```

What I'm missing is somehow encoding the "path": "/Backups" data specified by the doc into the request object.  I'm also missing how to encode the "Authorization" access token into the request.  (Above I'm using a username/password but that's probably wrong.)

Can anybody complete the VB.NET HTTP request for me?  Thanks very much.

** UPDATE new code based on helpful links from the_lotus -- this works, thanks!:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim uri As String = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder"
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.UserAgent = "api-explorer-client"

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer HBN-BvdIlsAAAFTyAQzhNJrBNINPIea7Jc1Ke")

    '{
    '"path": "/Backups"
    '}

    Dim json_data As String = "{"+ Chr(34) + "path" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + "/Backups" + Chr(34) + "}"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    Dim json_bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json_data)
    request.ContentLength = json_bytes.Length

    Dim stream As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream

    stream.Write(json_bytes, 0, json_bytes.Length)


    Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

    Debug.Print(response.StatusDescription)

    Dim dataStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(dataStream)          ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()  ' Read the content.

    MsgBox(responseFromServer)  ' Display the content.

    ' Cleanup the streams and the response.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You can [add information to the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158298/how-to-force-webrequest-to-send-authorization-header-during-post). As for the JSON, I would assume that is the actual [post information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request).

Comment: Oh, those are helpful.  I think I got closer, but I'm getting a 'bad request 400' on the GetResponse command.

Comment: (trying to add revised code...)

Comment: your JSON isn't properly formatted, missing some characters.

Comment: That worked!  Awesome, thanks so much!

Comment: good solution, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add custom header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158298/how-to-force-webrequest-to-send-authorization-header-during-post) with request.Headers.

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer HBN-BvdIlsAAAFTyAQzhNJrBNINPIea7Jc1Ke")
```

To [send the POST information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request), you can use request.GetRequestStream.

Also, make sure the data send in the POST is properly formatted JSON.